# How to change url of AVAsset on next page and come to the previous page without having memory issues iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I am building an app and the scenario is something like this:

I have 3 view controllers VC1,VC2,VC3.

scenario1
I have an AVPlayer on VC2 that uses a "NSURL" saved in userDefaults to play a video.Let us say that the key to this url is "videoURL".Now if I pop VC2 and go back to VC1,dealloc() gets called and everything gets deallocated and the video stops playing.So,if I change the "videoURL" on VC1 and then push VC2 onto the navigation stack,I get a new AVPlayer with the previous one being deallocated.No problems till now.

scenario2
If I change "videoURL" on VC2,I get a new playerItem using "replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem" to play a new video.No problems here as well.

scenario3
Now if I push VC3 onto the stack,I don't know how to play a new URL if I pop back to VC3.The video doesn't stop playing when I push VC3,even if I set AVPlayer to nil before pushing VC3.And when I do stop the video and push VC3,I am facing memory issues.

What is the correct way to implement scenario3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I am doing for the scenario3:

```
-(void)goToNextPage
{
//This stops the video....
 [player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:nil];
}
```

Now I am creating a delegate.So now VC2 acts as a delegate of VC3.So when I am on VC3,I write a code to generate a new Url,and pass that to a property in VC2.

So I came to a conclusion that I don't need to deallocate AVPlayer in VC2 as long as VC2 is loaded in memory.Also,the observers associated with it do not need to be removed as well.

Here is the complete demo of AVPlayer and its observers.I'm sure it will help each and everyone who is getting started with AVFoundation and observers.

//VC1

```
-(IBAction)gotoPlayer:(id)sender
{

  PlayerViewController *playerVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlayerViewController"];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:playerVC animated:YES];
}
```

//VC2.h

```
@interface PlayerViewController : UIViewController<ChangeUrlDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSURL *url;

-(void)playWithURL:(NSURL*)url_;

@end
```

//VC2.m

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self setPlayerDataOnPageArrival];
}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 if(self.url)
    [self playWithURL:self.url];
 else{
      NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"sample_mpeg4" ofType:@"mp4"];
      PlayerSource *source_ = [[PlayerSource alloc]initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path]];
      [self playWithURL:source_.sourceURL];
    }
}


-(void)dealloc
{

  NSLog(@"In playerViewController dealloc");
  [playerItem_ removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
  [player_ removeTimeObserver:self.timeObserver];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self   name:self.itemEndObserver object:playerItem_];
}


#pragma mark ChangeURLViewController delegate methods

-(void)newURL:(NSURL *)url_
{
  self.url = url_;
}


#pragma mark player methods

-(void)setPlayerDataOnPageArrival{

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"sample_mpeg4" ofType:@"mp4"];
PlayerSource *source_ = [[PlayerSource alloc]initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path]];
self.url = source_.sourceURL;
asset_ = [AVAsset assetWithURL:self.url];

playerItem_ = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset_];
NSLog(@"observer added");
[playerItem_ addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];

player_ = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem_];
playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player_];

}


-(void)playWithURL:(NSURL*)url_{

[playerLayer setFrame:self.playerView.frame];

if(self.playerView.layer.sublayers.count == 0)
    [self.playerView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
else{

    AVPlayerItem *newPlayerItem_ = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url_];
    [player_ replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:newPlayerItem_];

    NSLog(@"rate--->%f",player_.rate);
    if(player_.rate == 0 && player_.status == 1)
        player_.rate = 1;
    }
}


-(void)addPlayerItemTimeObserver{

CMTime interval = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.01,NSEC_PER_SEC);
 //   __weak PlayerViewController *weakSelf = self;
    self.timeObserver = [player_ addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:interval queue:dispatch_get_main_queue() usingBlock:^(CMTime time) {

    //NSLog(@"in addPlayerItemTimeObserver");

    CGFloat currentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(time);
    NSLog(@"currentTime--->%f",currentTime);
    }];
}


-(void)addItemEndObserverForPlayerItem{

//When playback completes,an AVPlayerItem posts a notification called "AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification"

self.itemEndObserver = AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserverForName:self.itemEndObserver object:nil queue:NULL usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {

    NSLog(@"in item end observer");
    }];
}



#pragma mark player status observer

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context{

NSLog(@"In observer");

if (playerItem_.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay) {

    NSLog(@"success");
    [self addPlayerItemTimeObserver];
    [self addItemEndObserverForPlayerItem];
    [player_ play];
}

else if(player_.status == AVPlayerItemStatusFailed){

    NSLog(@"failed");
}

else if(player_.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown){

    NSLog(@"Unknown");
    }  
}

#pragma mark action methods

-(IBAction)goToNextPage:(id)sender{

[player_ replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:nil];
ChangeURLViewController *changeUrlVC_ = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChangeURLViewController"];
changeUrlVC_.delegate=self;
self.url = nil;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:changeUrlVC_ animated:YES];

}


-(IBAction)changeURL:(id)sender{

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"sample_mpeg4" ofType:@"mp4"];
PlayerSource *source_ = [[PlayerSource alloc]initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path]];
[self playWithURL:source_.sourceURL];
}
```

//VC3.h

```
@protocol ChangeUrlDelegate <NSObject>

  -(void)newURL:(NSURL*)url_;

@end

@interface ChangeURLViewController : UIViewController

  @property (weak,nonatomic) id <ChangeUrlDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

//VC3.m

```
-(void)dealloc{

    NSLog(@"In changeURL dealloc");
}

-(IBAction)changeURLAction:(id)sender{

     NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"sample_mpeg4" ofType:@"mp4"];
    PlayerSource *source_ = [[PlayerSource alloc]initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path]];
    NSLog(@"delegate---->%@",self.delegate);
    [self.delegate newURL:source_.sourceURL];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }
```

NOTE:Note that you should use dealloc() in every view controller and it should get called overtime that view controller is removed from memory(popped off navigation stack).

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to add logic to view controller 2's viewWillDisappear method to stop and release the AVPlayer, and move the logic that creates the AVPlayer and starts it playing to viewWillAppear (so that when you pop view controller 3 and go back to view controller 2 you can play view controller 2's video again.)

How you do that depends on how you're managing the AVPlayer. Post your VC2 code that sets up the AVPlayer and installs its playback layer in VC2's layer hierarchy. (Edit your original question to include that information. Don't post code in comments. It's pretty much unreadable.)

Comment: Thanks Duncan but I wanted to have a go at it first.I guess I have done that.Correct me if I am wrong.I am posting the solution.